# jquery file upload plugin file upload without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload plugin for uploading files to my server but when server returns a json how to display that data without my page refreshing.I know that many posts says using iframe we can acheive i am very new to jquery and ajax can any figure it out and help me thank you in advance.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: "fileUpload.do?",
    type:"POST",
    autoUpload: true,
    formdata:{name:'FolderId',value:getfolderId()},
});


function getfolderId(){
    var FolderId
    alert();
    $('#fileupload').on("click",function(){
        FolderId=document.getElementById('currentFolder').value;
        document.getElementById('selectedFolder').value = FolderId;
    }); 
    return FolderId;
}`


          </form>`<form id="fileupload" on action="fileUpload.do" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div  class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                    <label for="form-upload">
                           <img src="htdocs/images/add_file.png"
                    style="width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 0" > 
                        </label>
                             <input  id="form-upload" type="file" name="upload" multiple style="opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity: 0);">
                             <im:hidden name="selectedFolder" id="selectedFolder" value="1" />
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                              <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                              </div>
                           <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                     </div>
                   </div>

              <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>

          </form>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addFile-link').bind("click",function(){
        var FolderId

        FolderId=document.getElementById('currentFolder').value;
        document.getElementById('selectedFolder').value = FolderId;

        if( FolderId==" " || FolderId==0){
            $('#input').prop('disabled', true);
            showFileMSg();
            //alert("kindly select a folder to upload files");

        }
        else{

            $('#input').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
         xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: "fileUpload.do?",
            type:"POST",
            dataType : "JSON",
            autoUpload: true,
           formdata:{name:'FolderId',value:FolderId},
           disableImagePreview:true,
           filesContainer: $('table.files'),
           uploadTemplateId: null,
           downloadTemplateId: null,
           uploadTemplate: function (o) {
               var rows = $();
               $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
                   var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
                       '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                       '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                       '<div class="error"></div>' +
                       '</td>' +
                       '<td><p class="size"></p>' +
                       '<div class="progress"></div>' +
                       '</td>' +
                       '<td>' +
                       (!index && !o.options.autoUpload ?
                           '<button class="start" disabled>Start</button>' : '') +
                       (!index ? '<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>' : '') +
                       '</td>' +
                       '</tr>');
                   row.find('.name').text(file.name);
                   row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
                   if (file.error) {
                       row.find('.error').text(file.error);
                   }
                   rows = rows.add(row);
               });
               return rows;
           },
           downloadTemplate: function (o) {
               var rows = $();
               $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
                   var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
                       '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                       '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                       (file.error ? '<div class="error"></div>' : '') +
                       '</td>' +
                       '<td><span class="size"></span></td>' +
                       '<td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>' +
                       '</tr>');
                   row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
                   if (file.error) {
                       row.find('.name').text(file.name);
                       row.find('.error').text(file.error);
                   } else {
                       row.find('.name').append($('<a></a>').text(file.name));
                       if (file.thumbnailUrl) {
                           row.find('.preview').append(
                               $('<a></a>').append(
                                   $('<img>').prop('src', file.thumbnailUrl)
                               )
                           );
                       }
                       row.find('a')
                           .attr('data-gallery', '')
                           .prop('href', file.url);
                       row.find('button.delete')
                           .attr('data-type', file.delete_type)
                           .attr('data-url', file.delete_url);
                   }
                   rows = rows.add(row);
               });
               return rows;
           },
           always:function (e, data) {
               $.each( function () {
                   $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
               });

           },
           done: function (e, data) {
               $('.template-upload').remove();
               $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                   openFolder(FolderId);
               });

           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
           }



             /*add: function (e, data) {
            $('body').append('<p class="upl">Uploading...</p>')
            data.submit();
        },*/
    })

        }

    });
```